# Using Lambda functions to Consume all objects provided by a Supplier

Tags: lambda, java-stream, java-9, consumer, supplier

Looking for how to use Java lambda functions so Consumer can process all objects provided by a Supplier, and get rid of the explicit `while` loop and `null` checks.

I have a Supplier of String keys for a database and I want to use a Consumer to process each of those keys.

```
Supplier<String> keyGen = new SimpleKeySupplier(keyPrefix, numKeys);
Consumer<String> consumer = (String key) -> System.out.println("key="+key);
```

I want `consumer` to process each key supplied by `keyGen` and tried the following. It works but I am sure that there must be a more concise way of using lambda functions to make this simpler.

```
    // Test that the correct keys have been populated.
    Supplier<String> keyGen = new SimpleKeySupplier(keyPrefix, NumKeys);
    String k = keyGen.get();
    while(k != null) {
        consumer.accept(k);
        k = keyGen.get();
    }
```

SimpleKeySupplier works, and a simplified version is presented below:

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class SimpleKeySupplier implements Supplier<String> {
    private final String keyPrefix;
    private final int numToGenerate;
    private       int numGenerated;

    public SimpleKeySupplier(String keyPrefix, int numRecs) {
        this.keyPrefix = keyPrefix;
        numToGenerate  = numRecs;
        numGenerated   = 0;
    }
    @Override
    public String get() {
        if (numGenerated >= numToGenerate) 
            return null; 
        else   
            return (keyPrefix + numGenerated++);
    }
}
```

The Consumer in this example is greatly simplified for posting on StackOverflow.

Comment: You are using the wrong tool for the job. Use `IntStream.range(0, numKeys).mapToObj(numGenerated-> keyPrefix + numGenerated) …`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
Supplier<String> keyGen = new SimpleKeySupplier(keyPrefix, numKeys);
Consumer<String> consumer = (String key) -> System.out.println("key="+key);
Stream.generate(keyGen).filter(s -> s !=null).limit(NumKeys).forEach(consumer);
```

Answer (score 6):

You may do it like so, with the new capabilities added in Java9.

```
Stream.generate(keyGen).takeWhile(Objects::nonNull).forEach(consumer);
```

Comment: Interestingly `Stream.generate` produces an *unordered stream* which helps further in using `takeWhile` efficiently.

Comment: @nullpointer actually, it breaks the operation. Since the stream is *unordered*, there is no constraint about how many elements it will actually process, when there is a `null` element, as it is allowed to behave as-if `null` was at an arbitrary position (*unordered* implies the absence of a meaningful position), including the first position. It may even try to consume elements “after” the `null` element, as “before” and “after” have no meaning in an unordered stream. You are right in that this will help optimizing `takeWhile` internally, but not in the way the OP wants…

Comment: @Holger  It looks like I should use filter(s -> s != null) rather than takeWhile(Objects::nonNull) to ensure I process them all except the null. In my case, order does not matter but if it did then what would you suggest I use as the right tool rather than generate(keyGen)? Thanks.

Comment: @ScottK “process them all” is not a good idea for an infinite stream. You need an ordered stream to correctly terminate when encountering `null`, e.g. `Stream.iterate(supplier.get(), Objects::nonNull, prev -> supplier.get()). …`, but as you can see, a `Supplier` is not a good starting point for that. I already provided the better alternative in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844760/using-lambda-functions-to-consume-all-objects-provided-by-a-supplier/53845097?noredirect=1#comment94579576_53844760).

Comment: @Holger Maybe I misunderstand you, but I use the Supplier class as that is the design pattern that I am given. In reality, the key Supplier and verification steps are much more complex than I have shown, and the two are decoupled. I would not be able to replace the Supplier Class with something of my own choosing.

Comment: @ScottK well, if you can’t replace the supplier, the `Stream.iterate` based solution of my previous comment may help.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `Stream`:

```
Stream.generate(keyGen).limit(NumKeys).forEach(consumer);
```

`Stream.generate` will create a stream that keeps calling `get` on the supplier provided.

`limit` makes the stream finite, limiting it to x elements. In this case, I can see that `keyGen` will only generate `NumKeys` keys, so I "cut off" the stream from that point.

Comment: This was an excellent solution, except in my case I needed to add a filter for the one Null record: filter(s -> s !=null). Now it works well. Thanks. Final Solution was: "Stream.generate(keyGen).limit(MaxRecs+1).filter(s -> s !=null).limit(MaxRecs).forEach(consumer);". Adding two filters was overkiil, and there are robustness problems since the line will hang if Supplier fails to deliver MaxRecs+1 keys.